# Insert data into array with specific index in Angular 4

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

Why that is not working in TypeScript?

Example:

```
views: any[] = [360001232825, 360001232845, 360001217389];
MyArray:any[];

     for (var i = 0; i < this.views.length; i++) {
            this.subscription = this.dataService.getMyData(this.views[i]).subscribe(data => {
                this.myArray[this.views[i]]=data;
            });
        }
```

When I use `.push` data is inserted into my array but I want to use a specific index.

Comment: How are you testing if this works or not?

Comment: where is defined this.myArray I think that you are trying to do a key map.

Comment: initizlize the array: MyArray:any[]=[]; Anyway, e.g. this.view[0]=360001232825. Are you sure you want to say this.MyArray[360001232825]=data? it's possible you want to say MyArray:any={} //an object

Comment: Thanks guys for your response !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to insert an Item use splice. But obviously you want to use a Map or an object.

```js
let ar = ["one", "two", "four", "five"];

console.log("Before:\n" + ar);
ar.splice(2, 0, "three");
console.log("After:\n" + ar);
```

Maybe this will help:

```js
let namedIndexes = [1564789, 234895, 249846];
let map = {}; 

let data = "this is your data arg";

namedIndexes.forEach((v, i, ar) => {
  map[v] = data + " data at " + v;
});

console.log(map);
```

'map' is like your this.myArray, 'data' is your parameter and 'namedIndexes' is your view array. I hope the code explains itself.

Comment: That what i want thanks ! And if i want to initialize my array with a specific index how can I do that ? { "Monday": 2,"Sunday":5}

Comment: yes that would work. Then you can do myArray["Monday"]